# Did termites eat my sentricon termite bates?

Tags: pest-control

We have Sentricon termite bait stations installed around the perimeter of our house.  This morning I pulled up a few of the bait stations and looked for evidence of termites.  But I'm not sure how to interpret the results.

Based on these images, did termites eat the bate?  Or is this degraded bate simply due to decay?

[image]

And another view

[image]

This is what the manufacturer says the bait stations look like when **no** termites have eaten the bait.

[image]